deploying c# project to azure func app from visual studio
A project is added as reference another project of the same solution, at the time of deployment it show error
Metadata file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\IKEA\IK\content-integration-api-backend\Komponera\obj\Release\net8.0\win-x64\ref\Komponera.dll' could not be found    ValidationLayer CSC
this means it is mentioned as there is no dll for the project you have added as a reference in current publishing project
Build is success but deployment fails

Could you share your .csproj files please?

The issue could be due to the version incompatibility between some of the dependencies or NuGet package not updated in one of the referenced libraries.
Refer MSDOC for possible solutions.

Check if the same project referenced twice. Add reference dll project to other projects.
Clean up all ERRORS and make sure the solutions/project stable.
Unload and re-load all the projects from the solution.
Clean and Rebuild every project individually.
Fix the target framework in .csproj:

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>


Align and check the build configuration: Build=>Configuration Manager, check if all the projects are using the same configuration.


Use below profile settings while deploying the function to Azure.

